# Turn a 1x336 array into a 16x21 array

Tags: python, numpy

I am attempting to make an 1x336 column array and fill it with data from the attribute tables of 336 feature classes.  I think I have succeeded this task.  Next, I would like to rearrange  this 1x336 array into a 16x21 array and save it as a txt file.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import numpy

arcpy.env.workspace="C:\Users\mbs7038\Documents\New_Landsat_Imagery\For_Area_Calc\Minimize_DEM_Analysis\PolyConvert\out_prj.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True


filename="C:\Users\mbs7038\Documents\New_Landsat_Imagery\For_Area_Calc\Minimize_DEM_Analysis\PolyConvert\areatable.txt"

fcs=arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*")
areafield="Area_km"

n=16
areaColumn=[]
arealist=numpy.zeros([16,21],dtype=numpy.float64)
areaset=set()
print arealist

for fc in fcs:
    print fc
    rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
    for row in rows:
        area=row.getValue(areafield)
        print area
        print 'appending area'
        if area not in areaset:
            areaColumn.append(area)
            print'adding area'
            areaset.add(area)
            print areaColumn

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(0,21):
        arealist[i,j]=areaColumn[:] #This is where I have been trying to call each row from areaColumn
        print arealist
```

I have also tried the reshape function with no success:

```
finalarea=arealist.reshape(arealist.size//16,21)
print finalarea
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out after reading more about lists and arrays.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import numpy

# Setup workspace
arcpy.env.workspace=r"C:\Users\mbs7038\Documents\New_Landsat_Imagery\For_Area_Calc\Minimize_DEM_Analysis\PolyConvert\out_prj.gdb"
# Enable overwriting
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True

# final output text file to be created
filename=r"C:\Users\mbs7038\Documents\New_Landsat_Imagery\For_Area_Calc\Minimize_DEM_Analysis\PolyConvert\areatable_Sorted.txt"

areaColumn=[] #create an empty list where area data can be stored (ends up being 1x336 after completing the first for loop)
areaset=set()

#===============================================================================
# get a list of all feature classes in env.workspace
fcs=arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*")
fcCount=len(fcs)  #print a count of the number of feature classes in the gdb
print fcCount
# feature class column where area in km2 is stored
areafield="Area_km"

fcs.sort()
for fc in fcs:                       # loop through each feature class
    print fc
    rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)    # list all rows in the feature class
    for row in rows:                 # loop through each row in the feature class
        area=row.getValue(areafield) # get the value stored in the field, "Area_km"
        print area
        print 'appending area'
        if area not in areaset:
            areaColumn.append(area)  # add the value to AreaColumn array
            print'adding area'
            areaset.add(area)
            print areaColumn

print'convert areaColumn list to an array'
initial=numpy.array(areaColumn,dtype=float) # convert the 1x336 list to a 1x336 array
print initial                               # print the new array, "initial"
initial.shape

print'resizing to 16x21 array'
finalArea=numpy.resize(initial,(16,21))     # resize the 1x336 array to a 16x21 array
print finalArea                             # print the resized array, "finalarea"

print 'saving finalarea array'
numpy.savetxt(filename,finalArea)           # save "finalarea" array to a text file
```

Answer (score 1):

You should know that reshape takes a tuple as an argument. The following should work:

```
finalarea = arealist.reshape((16,21))
```